# Proper Conversions for FPDF

Tags: php, fpdf

Here is my issue: I need to be able to create a table like format in FPDF; To do this I need to determine the size of arbitrary strings in various fonts.
Catch is: FPDF only works in physical measurements like mm or in.

Does anyone know a good way to convert a string, in whatever font, into a size I can use in FPDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, i see uou asks for FPDF and the below example is for TCPDF which i think is based on FPDF.

```
$string = 'Hello world';

//Whatever font

$tcpdf_object->SetFont('Helvetica', 'B', 9);

$width = $tcpdf_object->GetStringWidth($string);
$height = $tcpdf_object->GetStringHeight($width, $string);

$tcpdf_object->Multicell($width, $height, $string);
```

Comment: Ended up switching to TCPDF, it has way more tools.